# Динамическое добавление и показ нотификации

Tags: javascript

Имеется контроллер:

```
public function addcomment() {
        $input = \Request::all();
        if(!empty($input["comment"])) {
            $comment = Comment::create($input);
            \Session::flash("notify", "Ваш комментарий успешно добавлен!");
        } else {
            \Session::flash("error", "Ошибка добавления комментария! Заполните все поля!");
        }
        return view('layouts.notify');
    }
```

Имеется view нотификации

```
@if (Session::has("notify"))
<div class="notify bdrs">{{Session::get("notify")}}</div>
@elseif(Session::has("error"))
<div class="error bdrs">{{Session::get("error")}}</div>
@endif
```

Имеется страница, на которой происходит добавление комментариев.
view данной страницы.

```
<form method="post" action="addcomment">
<textarea name="comment"></textarea>
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Как сделать так, что бы после того как человек заполнил форму и нажал кнопку отправить, его не перекидывало на другую страницу, а все обработалось на текущей странице? и в  выдался результат?

Comment: перехватывайте событие `submit`, шлите пост запрос по ajax, ответ вставляйте куда хотите